# What is the formula for displaying a value if another value is in the same row in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula that populates the Location # value of the person that is in the same row and only if the person is in the Location Manager or the Assistant Location Manager columns. The screenshots show two different tabs of information. I am trying to populate the Location# cell in the first screenshot. Data will be pulled from the second screenshot. The formula should populate COL-04 for Jane Doe and COL-01 for John Doe. If they aren't in the two columns, then the cell should stay blank (" "). I hope I explained things clear enough. Thanks

[image: Formula Location]

[[image: Data]]

IfError is not working properly.

[image: Should be blank][image: Formula]

Comment: Using `index/match` combined with `iferror` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both the data starts from A1 and the LOCATION DATA sheet is named Sheet1, this should return the correct values:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!C:C,0)),INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!D:D,0))),"")
```

Formula not tested, might be missing a bracket or comma:

```
=IF(B1=" ","",IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!C:C,0)),INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!D:D,0))),""))
```

Comment: It is working, but I have an issue now that the Location# isn't becoming blank if the FullName cell to its right is blank. I think it is because I have a formula in place that is populating the FullName cells from another tab and a formula in place that populates the Location # in another tab as well. So it is looking at the data as if it is matching.

Comment: Screenshots are above

Comment: Are they blank or is there a space? Try testing the blank with `LEN` and see what it returns. I am suspecting that there is a space. A true blank would return a `0`

Comment: If it is a space, you can nest the above formula in an `IF` statement, such that it returns a blank when the fullname is empty. Check the edit.

Comment: I nested an if statement in the beginning of the formula, stating if the FullName cell is " ", then display " ", if not then continue with the iferror formula. It works now. Thank you all for your help.